# Does using "Newsletter" in my email campaign name prevent Google Analytics from tracking that campaign?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, email, tracking

I've had a successful email campaign series setup using Universal Analytics with the /collect `img` code for open rate, except there are two emails that are mysteriously not tracking.

Tracked opens properly:

```
<img src="http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=UA-5406459-1&cid=36200&t=event&ec=email&ea=open&el=1a5fc002&cs=newsletter&cm=email&cn=Public+Invite+Open&cm1=1" />
```

Did not track opens:

```
<img src="http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=UA-5606459-1&cid=36200&t=event&ec=email&ea=open&el=1a5fc002&cs=newsletter&cm=email&cn=Newsletter+2014+03+Open&cm1=1" alt="">
```

...and the other was `cn=Newsletter+2014+02+Open`, the similarity of which makes me wonder if it is something so simple as the naming convention of the campaign. However I can't find locate anything about disallowed names.